# SSL Connectivity issue between Azure AppService and an Internal SOAP service

Tags: azure, ssl, soap, azure-web-app-service

We are building a booking service using Azure AppService. The app service exposes a booking API. The booking API calls an inventory SOAP service running within the company internal network to check the availability of items.

The inventory service is protected by internal firewall. To establish connectivity between the Azure AppService (booking service) and the internal service (inventory service), we have a firewall connection opened. The internal inventory service accepts only SSL connection.

The issue we have is when the Azure AppService tries to connect to the internal service it throws the below error:

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond..
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

The above error seems to indicate a problem with initial SSL handshake between the Azure AppService (booking service) and the internal service (inventory service).

The question I have is: Do we need to install a certificate on the Azure Appservice so it can connect to the internal inventory service. I am aware the internal inventory service has server certificate installed.

Comment: You might have a badly configured firewall. Maybe the message is going to the inventory SOAP service but it's not coming back. Have you tried to access the inventory SOAP service endpoint from the Azure server? You can open a command line and try to ask for something from the inventory server, like the WSDL of the service, or performing a GET on the inventory SOAP endpoint and see if you get back the same SSL error message or if the server responds with the WSDL or "method not allowed", or whatever else response you should receive from a GET request.

Comment: Also, try looking tin the firewall logs and see what happens, maybe you need to whitelist IPs, etc...

Comment: Thanks @Bogdan for your response.
To test the connectivity in command line, I created a curl command and tested the command while connected to the internal network from my laptop and it worked. I then tried the same curl command on the Azure AppService > Advanced Settings> Kudu commandline editor, It came back with the below error:
'OpenSSL SSL_connect: Connection was reset in connection to inventoryservice.xxxxdomain.com:443'. 
So the issue is still connectivity.
I will check if there is a white listing required tomorrow.